# Initialize method from HashSet

Tags: java, hashset

I have added the element `spells.add(new Magic("boring",2,true));` and similar, but when I try to run

```
for (Magic set : spells) {
        Magic magic1 = new Magic(spells);
        magic1.go();
}
```

I get the error `no suitable constructor found for Magic(java.util.HashSet<Magic>`

If I change `Magic magic1 = new Magic(spells);` to `Magic magic1 = new Magic("boring",2,true)`, I get the results I was looking for, but I want to be able to use a HashSet.

How can I make the contents of the HashSet usable?

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand?

Comment: I understand the error. I am asking how to make a HashSet's information usable.

Comment: As the error is trying to tell you, you can only pass a parameter to a constructor if the constructor accepts that type.

Comment: Why have you deleted the comments you added to my answer?

Comment: I realized that I had entered the code wrong and your code worked. My comments were irrelevant and pointless.

Comment: Right - it would have been a good idea to add that as a comment into the thread rather than just silently deleting them, leaving my comments hanging in the wind. I'll delete mine now as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you constructing a *new* `Magic` instance within the loop (or trying to, anyway)? Surely you just need the ones in the set:

```
for (Magic spell : spells) {
    spell.go();
}
```

Note that currently you're ignoring the `set` variable in your loop as well - which I've renamed to `spell` to be more obvious. Whenever you find yourself declaring a variable and then ignoring it, that's a hint that something's wrong...